# SlideToggle and Callback, am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Tags: jquery, callback, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup

I have a page with Four Item buttons, when the user click on these buttons the Content should slideDown.

If it is already a visible content this content must be slided up and then the right content should be slided Down.

Everything works fine, but if the user click fast between the Item Buttons the slides get jammed and start to appear on top of the others.

Here is an example.:
http://jsfiddle.net/7t6Eh/42/

If the user click "slow" between the Items, everything works ok.

- To re-create the error Click Fast Between the Item Buttons.

I've already tried to use '.is(": visible")' but got the same results.

Can anyone help me out?

### CODE

```
var active = 0;

    $("#item1").click(function(){

        if (active == 0){

            $("#ContentList1").stop().slideToggle(function() {
                active = 1;
            });

        } else {

            if (active != 1){
                $("#ContentList" + active).stop().slideToggle(function() {

                    $("#ContentList1").stop().slideToggle(function() {
                        active = 1;
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    });

    $("#item2").click(function(){

        if (active == 0){

            $("#ContentList2").stop().slideToggle(function() {
                active = 2;
            });

        } else {

            if (active != 2){
                $("#ContentList" + active).stop().slideToggle(function() {

                    $("#ContentList2").stop().slideToggle(function() {
                        active = 2;
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    });

    $("#item3").click(function(){

        if (active == 0){

            $("#ContentList3").stop().slideToggle(function() {
                active = 3;
            });

        } else {

            if (active != 3){
                $("#ContentList" + active).stop().slideToggle(function() {

                    $("#ContentList3").stop().slideToggle(function() {
                        active = 3;
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    });    

    $("#item4").click(function(){

        if (active == 0){

            $("#ContentList4").stop().slideToggle(function() {
                active = 4;
            });

        } else {

            if (active != 4){
                $("#ContentList" + active).stop().slideToggle(function() {

                    $("#ContentList4").stop().slideToggle(function() {
                        active = 4;
                    });

                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you also include the code within your post please?  This question should remain useful long after the demo link goes dead.

Comment: Hey @Sparky672, you´re right. I´ve just put the code on the question too. Thks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usuallly do this kind of things taking advantage of `siblings()` to select adjacent divs and stop them, rather than using an "active" var to store the active div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#item1").click(function(){
        $('#' + $(this).attr('for'))
            .slideDown().siblings('div').stop().slideUp()
    });
    $("#item2").click(function(){
        $('#' + $(this).attr('for'))
            .slideDown().siblings('div').stop().slideUp()
    });
    $("#item3").click(function(){
        $('#' + $(this).attr('for'))
            .slideDown().siblings('div').stop().slideUp()
    });
    $("#item4").click(function(){
        $('#' + $(this).attr('for'))
            .slideDown().siblings('div').stop().slideUp()
    });
});
```

you can use the "for" attribute (or any other) to specify the div that the link is referring. For example:

```
<div id="item1" for="ContentList1" style="float: left; width: 50px; cursor: pointer;">Item1</div>
```

​
An example working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7t6Eh/46/

**ADDED**: If you want to do the close animation before the open animation, you can use jQuery deferred like this:

```
$("#item1").click(function(){
    content = $('#' + $(this).attr('for'));
    $.when(content.siblings('div').stop().slideUp())
        .then(function () { content.slideDown() });
});
```

of course apply to all 4 click events. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7t6Eh/52/

Comment: Hello Matte, great tip, i didn´t know about siblings, it´s very useful. Your example really fix the overlap problem but the "visual" aspect is not the same. The Content appears on top of the previous one. There is a way to first slideUp the Old Content, and then slideDown the new content ? Or i can´t get this result without the Overlap Problem ? I´ve tried to make some tests on your code but did not work.

Comment: I've added a solution to the answer. You can use deferreds like `.when()` and `.then()` to time your animations. :)

Comment: Colleen you are right, we were trying to prove a point only :) Ideally yes, he does not even need .each() but simply use a selector that encompasses the 4 links, maybe giving them a class.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/7t6Eh/50/

This should do what you are trying to achieve.
It gets the position of the list item clicked and shows the content you want based on that.
Let me know f you need anything else explained

```
var active = -1;
$('.content').hide();
$('ul li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index('ul li');
    if( active == index) {
        // this item already active, do nothing
    } else {
        // show the content you want
        $('.content').stop().slideUp();
        $('.content').eq(index).slideDown()
    }
    active = index
})
```

​

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Selven, it works great! But i still have one question. There is a way to tweak your code to achieve the same visual aspect of my first post ? The active content should slideUp, and after that the New Content will slideDown. I´ve tried put a small delay jut before the slideDown.: "$('.content').delay(1000).eq(index).slideDown()", but the Overlap problem appears again.